# Max has no fillna

Tags: python, pandas

`max()` has no `fillna`

I need to output the max value and then change it with `strptime`, but I need to output the max after making sure I don't have NaT values.

this is the line that I have and it works, but not how I want:

```
print(datetime.strptime(str(x.iloc[:i-1, 2].fillna(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:01')).max()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The problem is that fillna is designed for dataframes, but in between I need to find the maximum value.

What I want to achieve is:

```
print(datetime.strptime(str(x.iloc[:i-1, 2].max().fillna(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:01'))), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Why not transform the series into a dataframe using `to_frame()` or `x.iloc[:i-1, [2]]`? Do any of those work?

Comment: Today I am not agile, I think it should work, thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `x`? And the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

FTR, using [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html#pandas-series-to-frame) should be enough to transform the output of `.max()` from a `pd.Series` into a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it returns this:
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Is this how it should be?
`print(datetime.strptime(str(x.iloc[:i-1, 2].max().to_frame().fillna(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:01'))), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't get exactly your issue. What's your expected output? Also, why would you need to `.fillna` after using `max`? You would already have the maximum value in the series